# mikrotik joining two subnets

Tags: networking

I have two subnets which are geographically separated, connected by a wireless point to point link (5Mbps). Both networks are connected to internet through their own separate ILL WAN links which are configured on MikroTik routers. I want to connect the subnets through the routers. 
The scenario is :

Site 1:

```
192.168.10.0/24 
Ether1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx ---- connected to Internet
Ether2 192.168.10.1/24    ---- connected to local LAN

10.10.10.0/24 
Ether1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx ---- connected to Internet
Ether2 10.10.10.1/24      ---- connected to local LAN
```

I want to connect the two LANs together so that there is a seamless traffic between the two.

NO FIREWALL rules on either routers.
Only source NAT masquerade on WAN links on both routers.
NO destination NAT

I have tried the below, which, obviously does not work.

Site 1:

```
192.168.10.0/24 
Ether1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx ---- connected to Internet
Ether2 192.168.10.1/24    ---- connected to local LAN
Ether3 10.10.10.10/24     ---- P2P between Site 1 and 2
```

Site 2

```
10.10.10.0/24 
Ether1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx ---- connected to Internet
Ether2 10.10.10.1/24      ---- connected to local LAN
Ether3 192.168.10.10/24   ---- P2P between Site 1 and 2
```

What am I missing? (Beside, looks like everything?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need a VPN connection.

Go to the Interface tab, select EoIP and add a new interface in both routers.

After you just could bridge the interfaces with a port or add a private subnet to both EoIP virtual interfaces.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I can't determine that `Ether3` is physical Ethernet or a VPN interface.

BTW, you need a Site-To-Site or RemoteAccess VPN between two routers. Then add a route to subnet behind every router in another one, i.e add route to `10.10.10.1/24` in site 1's router. The gateway will be VPN IP address of remote router.